# Div elements blink when applying -webkit-transform (only elements after the transformed)

Tags: jquery, css, webkit, webkit-transform

I have a very strange issue:

I've got a DIV structure like this one to show some products on a website:

```
<div class="visible_frame"> //THIS FRAME HAS A FIXED SIZE AND OVERFLOW:HIDDEN
    <div class="wide_container>  //THIS CONTAINER IS AS WIDE AS ALL PAGES TOGETHER
        <div class="page">  //EACH PAGE IS FLOATED AND HIDDEN BEHIND THE FRAME
            <div class="product"> //EACH PRODUCT IS FLOATED INSIDE THE PAGE
                <div class="product_overlay"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="product">
                <div class="product_overlay"></div>
               //EACH OVERLAY IS HIDDEN INSIDE PRODUCT AND MOVES UP ON HOVER
            </div>
            <div class="product">
                <div class="product_overlay"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="page">
            <div class="product">
                <div class="product_overlay"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="product">
                <div class="product_overlay"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="product">
                <div class="product_overlay"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Well, you can see an aprox. copy of my code. I animate the PRODUCT_OVERLAY with a webkit-transform, so it covers the product completely on hover. What happens is, just when initating the movement and just when terminating it, ALL products AFTER the one being hovered blink (disappear and appear) for a few milliseconds.

What is even more strange, it only happens when I've got 3 OR MORE pages (I move WIDE_CONTAINER horizontally to switch pages, like in a carousel).

I guess it could be due to tons of things, as it's a bit complicated structure, but the fact it only happens to the products AFTER the one being hovered and NEVER when there is 1 or 2 pages makes me think there's something I don't see...

Here is the JSFIDDLE of the 3-page case (where the issue happens):

http://jsfiddle.net/BVV24/1/

And here the 2-page cas (I only changed the HTML, removing one page):

http://jsfiddle.net/BVV24/2/

BTW, I just noticed this only happens in Safari (webkit) and not in Google Chrome (also webkit)...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are likely to get quick answers with jsfiddle.

Comment: Just added the jsfiddles for both cases! Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Also solution

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332485/transformscale-causing-blinking-when-hovering
```